# Application for android to display contents from a PC which connected thru wifi

Tags: android

am new to this application developer, first I'll describe the setup of my system. I've one mechanical machine, it connected with a PC via PLC, now I've some data ( decimal numbers) in PC (which is from machine), now 
I need to develop an application to display contents (decimal numbers) in the android mobile, which is in PC via WiFi.

And i need to send some command back to PC,

Is it possible with simple application developer with simple coding?

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it only with your PC<->Mobile, you could expose the data-file via a webserver and then let the mobile read that file and expose in a desired manner. This is not a suggested way to do it, as it has several draw backs e.g. limiting exposed data etc.

Assuming that the data you want to expose is not trivial and may contain multiple data sources, Doing it in more-interoperable way will be a bit more work.

1. Write webservices (REST/SOAP) that expose the data from the server
2. Write an mobile app that consume the data from the webservice (via a REST client)
3. Once the app has consumed the data, you can write your
       desired ui to display it on the mobile app.

Comment: dear friends thanks for your reply... i'll try those options... how about creating a web page in PC and can browse in mobile? will it work?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily use TCP sockets which are based on IP protocol and will allow you to communicate over any IP network.

**For your Server/PC**

you can write a simple java tcp server on your PC.

Tutorials:

- [TCP Server](http://systembash.com/content/a-simple-java-tcp-server-and-tcp-client/)
- [All About Sockets](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/) ... great starting point.

**For your Android/Client**

you will have to understand the basics on android development and take a look at couple of networking example.

follow these links:

- [Your First Android App](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html)
- [Android TCP Client Example](http://myandroidsolutions.blogspot.com/2012/07/android-tcp-connection-tutorial.html)

Extra :

- [TCP on Wikipedia](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/) no need to read the implimentation details just understand the concept.

Comment: dear friends thanks for your reply... i'll try those options... how about creating a web page in PC and can browse in mobile? will it work?